# How to popup TitleWindow in Module using Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am working on flex.
I want to open TitleWindow in flex Module.

My Main page is Application Page and I want to open Module page from Main Page.
In Module page there is TitleWindow control.
I want to popup title window in Module Page.

Please help me......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make title Window as a custom component, So that you open up with popup manager in Module.